# Powershell if Statement not working

Tags: powershell

I am not so much familiar with scripting, currently Im trying a script to check the ssid that you are connected to.
If it is secured it will display you are secure and if you are connected to an open wifi it will tell you that you are not secure.

Script below

```
function Test-WiFiSecured{
    $props = netsh wlan show interfaces | 
        Select-Object -skip 4 |
        Where{$_.Trim()} |
        ForEach-Object{ $_ -replace ':', '=' } |
        Out-String |
        ConvertFrom-StringData
    $wifi = [pscustomobject]$props
    Write-Host 'Authentication='$wifi.Authentication -ForeGround Green
    if($wifi.Profile -eq 'Open'){
        Write-Host 'Not secure' -ForeGround Red
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Secure connection' -ForeGround Green
        return $true
    }
}
Test-WiFiSecured
```

Any assistance is appreciate since Im totally out of ideas now

Thanks

Comment: And what's your error here? What exactly is not working?

Comment: WhenAuthentication is Open it is still marking is as secure, whilst it should mark it as Not Secure

Answer (score 3):

You are checking for `$wifi.Profile -eq 'Open'` but `$wifi.Profile` is the profile name, usually the SSID you are connected to. Probably you have to compare `$wifi.Authentication`. However, you can easily verify the correct property by output the `$wifi` object.

Comment: Issue solved when changing $wifi.profile -eq 'open' to $wifi.authentication -eq 'open'

Comment: @kurtattard If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)